# Is this better detection and Gaussian noise cancellation technique than Matched Filter

Tags: filters, signal-detection, denoising, soft-question

The code below generates four sinusoids and considered as known signal. One needs to find the location of the signals under additive Gaussian noise.

The known signals is comprise of four sinusoids with random phase and amplitude and at random location in time samples.

As I understand Matched filter is the only option. The algorithm below detects the location of the signals without using enrgy and compare the results with matched filter output.

Blue is matched filter output and the red is the new algorithm's output. As you can see the inputs to the algorithm (code/functiom) Nfilter is unity norm. Is such algorithm useful.

I have shown only one plot.

**EDIT**:  I have added a measure to quantify the noise removing capability of the new algorithim, compare to the matched filter. It shows higher noise reduction, thus it added additional information. In the measure, only the energy of the single time location is considered as the desired signal and the other samples are noise. Ideally we want all other samples to be zero and the location
of time samples as 1, which is ideal but not possible. Therefore the measure of the alogorithim is the ratio of  on summation of the time samples with signal (3 time samples in this case) to that of all the samples.

**EDIT** There may be perfect nonlinear function to achieve the same result but in this case we are using unity norm signals so such possibility of such amplitude dependent nonlinear function does not exit.
[image]

### Code below

```
close all
clear all
clc
counter=1;
for k4=1:10
    for dB=0:-2:-0
        t=.01:.01:.5;
        L=length(t);
        % Random frequencies)
        f1=5;%*rand(1,1);
        f2=23;%*rand(1,1);
        f3=26.1;%*rand(1,1);
        f4=20;%*rand(1,1);
        % Sum of 4 sinusoids with random amolitude and phase
        matF=20*sin(2*f1*t+rand(1,1))+20*sin(2*f2*t+rand(1,1))+20*sin(3*t+rand(1,1))+sin(2*f4*t+rand(1,1));
%         matF=20*rand(1,1)*sin(2*f1*t+rand(1,1))+20*rand(1,1)*sin(2*f2*t+rand(1,1))+20*rand(1,1)*sin(3*t+rand(1,1))+sin(2*f4*t+rand(1,1));
        sM=max(max(abs(matF)));
        amp=sM*1/(10^(dB/20));
        % Random number os time samles between interested signals
        n1=ceil(200*rand(1,1));
        n2=ceil(200*rand(1,1));
        n3=ceil(200*rand(1,1));
        n4=ceil(200*rand(1,1));
        n5=ceil(200*rand(1,1));
        n6=ceil(200*rand(1,1));
        % 3 locations of the correct sample number
        correctSamples=[n1+ceil(L/2)+1,n1+ceil(L/2)+1+n2+n3+L,n1+ceil(L/2)+1+n2+n3+L+n4+n5+L];
        % Simulated signals with noise
        y=[amp*randn(1,n1),matF+amp*randn(1,length(t)),amp*randn(1,n2),amp*randn(1,n3),matF+amp*randn(1,length(t)),amp*randn(1,n4),amp*randn(1,n5),matF+amp*randn(1,length(t)),amp*randn(1,n6)];
        % Matched filter output
        y1=conv(y,flip(matF));
        timeStamp=linspace(1,length(y),length(y));

        for k=ceil(L/2):length(y)-ceil(L/2)
            % Matched filter output same as y1 worte as a function
            uF(ceil(L/2)+k)=matfilter(y(k-ceil(L/2)+1:k+ceil(L/2)),matF);
            temp1=y(k-ceil(L/2)+1:k+ceil(L/2))/norm(y(k-ceil(L/2)+1:k+ceil(L/2)));
            temp2=matF/norm(matF);
            % Output of the filter. Notice that the input to the function (Nfilter) has
            % unity norm
            [a,b]=Nfilter(temp1,temp2);
            uNew(ceil(L/2)+k)=a;
                    uNew1(ceil(L/2)+k)=b;
        end
        % normalized output it is desired as input is unity norm
        %     normalizeduNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))=uNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))/max(abs(uNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))))*max(abs(uF(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))));
        normalizeduNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))=uNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))/max(abs(uNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))));
        ufNormalized(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))=(uF(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))/max(abs(uF(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L)))));
        % plots
        figure
%         plot(y1(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))/max(abs(y1(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L)))),'g')
        hold on
        hold on
        plot(abs(ufNormalized(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))));
        plot(normalizeduNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L)),'r');
        signalMatchedFilter(counter)=0;
        signalFilter(counter)=0;
        for kk=1:3
            plot(correctSamples(kk),uF(correctSamples(kk)+L/2-1)/max(abs(uF(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L)))),'.','MarkerSize',50)
            signalMatchedFilter(counter)= signalMatchedFilter(counter)+abs(ufNormalized(correctSamples(kk)+L/2-1));
            signalFilter(counter)= signalFilter(counter)+abs(normalizeduNew(correctSamples(kk)+L/2-1));
            plot(correctSamples(kk),uNew(correctSamples(kk)+L/2-1)/max(abs(uNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L)))),'.','MarkerSize',30)
        end
        snrMat(counter)=signalMatchedFilter(counter)/sum(abs(ufNormalized(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))));
        snrFil(counter)=signalFilter(counter)/sum(abs(normalizeduNew(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L))));
        counter=counter+1;
        grid on
        str = sprintf('Comparison %d dB',dB);
        title(str)
        ylabel(" Filtered output")
        xlabel("Time samples")
%         figure
%         plot(uNew1(L/2:length(y1)-ceil(L)))
    end

end
snrFil./snrMat
%
ans =

  Columns 1 through 7

    4.1036    4.0983    4.5437    3.8723    3.2108    4.0537    3.8704

  Columns 8 through 10

    6.5755    8.4676    3.4302

         

Published with MATLAB® R2020b
```

The same algorithim can be used to denoise sonar signals. Consider 26 element (transducer/sensor) linear array receiving return from 3 targets at the same from three different directions under additive Gaussian noise. The first plot shows the result of usual Fourier Transform beamforming after denoising and the second plot is also Fourier beamforming but **no** denoising.
[image]
[image]

With more processing we get:
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**: The above plots were for narrow band signal. The following plots are for siganls of 10KHz bandwidth. It should be clear that higher bandwidth of signal will give sharp peak at the detection time on the hand the there is no noise reduction on the noise alone time. There seems to be suggestion that higher bandwith would denoise, noise also.[image]
[image]

Comment: Cool! Definitely looks cleaner! Looking at the code, are you just filtering your signal (normalized) with a (normalized) version of the original matched filter? In which case it’s the same *algorithm* per se… but a nice denoising method :)

Comment: It definitely seems like it could have some application. I believe some comms applications could use it for sure. Some applications with very low SNRs would probably not benefit from it however, if it has the possibility to miss the location in low SNR environments.

Comment: @Jdip, Thank you for your comment. We can remove the line max(abs(uF)) with a constant number for dectection purpose. The number can be appplication dependent.

Comment: @Baddioes Thank you for your comment. One can do similiar with  lower SNR also with one variable parameter. I have tried upto -3dB and it works.

Comment: @Creator I guess it depends on what you value more. This does some "denoising" which is nice, but if your goal is to pull out a signal from noise resulting with the highest SNR possible, then the matched filter would be a better choice. If you can, could you post all of the code so it can be run? This is interesting.

Comment: @Envidia, not sure what you mean by "pull out a signal", we already know the signal. It is the matched filter. we need the location only.

Comment: @Creator We know the signal we want, but the incoming signal is technically usually unknown. The matched filter is used to detect it, and it also gives you its delay based on some time reference.

Comment: @Envidia may I ask what other information you take except the location from matched filter? I can understand the use of any other filter. Time delay you mention is exactly the location in time.

Comment: @ Creator Depending on your waveform, you can also determine any phase differences incurred from the signals from the cross-correlation you ultimately calculate. If you know your noise floor, you can also estimate what kind of power levels/SNR was received before the matched filter. There's a few other considerations such as how closely spaced the signals can be before you're unable to discriminate between the two, but that is based on the waveform design (in this case how long your sinusoids are).

Comment: @Envidia, Thank you for your comments, I understand the relavents issues but it does not tell, what information you take from the output of the mtched filter other than the time estimation or delay?

Comment: @Envidia Just added two plots how the same algorithm can be used to denoise sonar signals. I would love to see how the algorithms works on radar data, if you have some.

Comment: @Creator Last comment before going into discussion chat. From your point of view I think the extraction of information is your main concern. If that's the case, then I think your analysis of some algorithm vs the matched filter is somewhat of a non-starter. The matched filter is mainly intended to detect a signal and yield the highest possible SNR gain against white noise. Any other things you do such as denoising come after that. For example, applying a CFAR detector and zeroing out samples that don't cross a threshold, would yield something similar as what you've shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152070/discussion-between-creator-and-envidia).